# Como imprimir 4 padrões de triângulos um ao lado do outro em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop

Preciso escrever um programa que imprime 4 padrões de triângulos, um ao lado do outro, separados por três espaços horizontais, como nessa imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para resolver isso, escrevi o seguinte código:

```
for i in range(10):
    print((i + 1) * "*")

print()

for i in range(10, -1, -1):
    print((i + 1) * "*")

print()

for i in range(9, -1, -1):
    print(f'{(i + 1) * "*" : >10}')

print()

for i in range(10):
    print(f'{(i + 1) * "*" : >10}')
```

O problema desse código é que ele imprime um triângulo embaixo do outro. Como posso imprimi-los lado a lado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode aproveitar [as opções já existentes para formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), já que no fundo o problema consiste em alinhar textos à direita ou esquerda, e a linguagem já tem isso pronto.

Por exemplo, na coluna "a", temos strings de um ou mais asteriscos alinhadas à esquerda, com no máximo 10 caracteres (sendo que se a string tiver menos que 10, é completado com espaços). Isso pode ser conseguido usando-se o formato `{:<10}`: o `<` indica alinhamento à esquerda, e o 10 indica o tamanho total.

Para a coluna "b", pode-se até usar o mesmo raciocínio, e fazer algumas contas para obter a quantidade de asteriscos (como fez a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440012/112052)), mas você também pode pensar de outra maneira: são strings contendo zero ou mais espaços, alinhadas à direita, e se a string não tiver tamanho suficiente, é completado com `*`. Isso pode ser feito com o formato `{:*>10}`: é quase igual ao anterior, mas o `*` indica o caractere que será usado para preencher as posições faltantes. Já o `>` indica alinhamento à direita, e 10 é o tamanho total.

Para as colunas "c" e "d", o comportamento é similar. A coluna "c" é o mesmo que "b", só que os espaços são alinhados à esquerda, e a coluna "d" é o mesmo que "a", só que os asteriscos são alinhados à direita. Então ficaria assim:

```
# recebe a quantidade de triângulos e opcionalmente um separador
def triangulos(qtd, sep='   '):
    asteriscos = '*'
    espacos = ''
    print(('{:<{n}}' * 3).format('(a)', '(b)', '(c)', '(d)', n=qtd + len(sep)))
    for _ in range(qtd):
        print('{0:<{n}}{2}{1:*>{n}}{2}{1:*<{n}}{2}{0:>{n}}'.format(asteriscos, espacos, sep, n=qtd))
        asteriscos += '*'
        espacos += ' '

triangulos(10)
```

A função `triangulos` recebe a quantidade de triângulos e opcionalmente um separador, que será colocado entre os triângulos (se não for indicado, serão 3 espaços).

Em seguida eu uso os formatos já descritos acima. Os números antes do `:` indicam o parâmetro a ser impresso ali (zero indica o primeiro valor passado para [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), 1 indica o segundo, etc). Por exemplo, `{0:<{n}}` indica que o primeiro parâmetro de `format` (a string `asteriscos`) será alinhada à esquerda, ocupando no máximo `n` posições (sendo que `n` é a quantidade passada como parâmetro para a função).

Para o cabeçalho eu usei `'{:<{n}}' * 3`, que gera a string `'{:<{n}}{:<{n}}{:<{n}}'`, e o tamanho `n` é a quantidade de triângulos mais o tamanho do separador (não considerei que o próprio separador será impresso aqui, apenas coloquei a quantidade de espaços para que o cabeçalho fique alinhado com os triângulos). Eu coloquei 3 e não 4, pois a última string (`'(d)'`) não precisa estar alinhada, já que não tem mais nada depois dela.

A saída é:

```
(a)          (b)          (c)          (d)          
*            **********   **********            *
**           *********     *********           **
***          ********       ********          ***
****         *******         *******         ****
*****        ******           ******        *****
******       *****             *****       ******
*******      ****               ****      *******
********     ***                 ***     ********
*********    **                   **    *********
**********   *                     *   **********
```

---

Testando com outros parâmetros:

```
triangulos(5, sep=' | ')
```

Saída:

```
(a)     (b)     (c)     (d)     
*     | ***** | ***** |     *
**    | ****  |  **** |    **
***   | ***   |   *** |   ***
****  | **    |    ** |  ****
***** | *     |     * | *****
```

---

Se estiver usando Python >= 3.6, pode usar [*f-strings*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) para formatar. Fica um pouco diferente, mas a ideia geral é a mesma:

```
def triangulos(qtd, sep='   '):
    asteriscos = '*'
    espacos = ''
    n = qtd + len(sep)
    print(f'{"(a)":<{n}}{"(b)":<{n}}{"(c)":<{n}}(d)') # o último (d) não precisa de alinhamento
    for _ in range(qtd):
        print(f'{asteriscos:<{qtd}}{sep}{espacos:*>{qtd}}{sep}{espacos:*<{qtd}}{sep}{asteriscos:>{qtd}}')
        asteriscos += '*'
        espacos += ' '
```

Answer (score 3):

É bem simples porém eu tive que escrever tudo do zero, pois não consegui reutilizar seu código.

O que você precisa fazer é percorrer cada linha do desenho que aparecerá, formatando a string utilizando espaçamentos, e depois definir um espaçamento **x** no parâmetro `end`, dessa forma:

```
max_size = 10
spacing = 3

for i in range(1, max_size + 1):

    # Primeiro triângulo
    print("*" * i, end = " " * (max_size - i + spacing))

    # Segundo triângulo
    print("*" * (max_size - i + 1), end = " " * (i - 1 + spacing))

    # Terceiro triângulo
    print(" " * (i - 1) + "*" * (max_size - i + 1), end = " " * spacing)

    # Quarto triângulo
    print(" " * (max_size - i) + "*" * i)
```

No código eu imprimi cada linha de cada triângulo no mesmo loop definindo um espaço de `3` caracteres entre eles. Dessa forma, eles podem ser desenhados horizontalmente.

**Extra:**

Para deixar idêntico o desenho com a sua imagem, eu escrevi esse simples código para você colocar em cima dos triângulos as letras `(a) (b) (c) (d)` formatadas.

```
print(
    "(a)" + " " * (max_size - 3 + spacing) +
    "(b)" + " " * (max_size - 3 + spacing) +
    "(c)" + " " * (max_size - 3 + spacing) +
    "(d)" + " " * (max_size - 3 + spacing)
    )
```